Docker Build Error: exit code: 127 - Maven Command Not Found and ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key
I'm trying to build a Docker image for a Java application using Maven, but I'm encountering an error during the Docker build process. Here's my Dockerfile:
# Build stage
FROM eclipse-temurin:21 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
#mvn clean package -DskipTests

# Runtime stage
FROM eclipse-temurin:21
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/target/uprightcleaningservices-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]



When I try to build the Docker image, I get the following error:
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn clean package -DskipTests" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127

The mvn clean package -DskipTests command is supposed to compile and package my Maven project.
I am using the eclipse-temurin:21 image as the base for both the build and runtime stages.
The build stage seems to fail because it cannot find the mvn command.

This I have tried

Verified that the target directory is correctly specified and that Maven builds the project successfully on my local machine.
Checked the Dockerfile for correct paths and commands.
Tried using a different base image, but the issue persists.

I expect the docker image to run successfully so I can deploy the application to render

You are using a Docker image for a JDK distribution that doesn't include Maven. Instead you should use a Maven image like https://hub.docker.com/_/maven. You can select an image with different JDK distribution and version in addition to Maven version.
Example:
FROM maven:3.9.8-eclipse-temurin-21

